# Samtools sort: most efficient memory and thread settings for many samples on a cluster

Tags: sequence-alignment, sequence-analysis, samtools, benchmarking

We're preparing to analyze thousands of `.bam` files beginning with re-alignment, sorting, etc.

**Complicated question:** Has anyone investigated the optimal thread and memory settings to sort hundreds to thousands of `.bam` files using `samtools sort` on a cluster?

By 'optimal', I'm looking to sort as many samples as possible in the shortest time frame. I'm mostly interested in optimizing `samtools sort` because the other steps (e.g., alignment) are much more obvious to fine-tune.

For a single sample, throwing large amounts of memory + threads is trivial, but that isn't scalable for thousands of samples. There is also likely a [diminishing return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns) at a certain point, even for a single sample.

Ideally, I'd like to see plots identifying the 'sweet spot' for threads + memory for a single sample (e.g., x == threads, y == memory, z == time), and then plots maximizing throughput for more samples. I would expect the data to follow a -log function, where we could identify the optimal settings at the [knee in the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knee_of_a_curve#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20knee%20of,or%20in%20the%20other%20direction.).

There are obviously many other factors (e.g., cluster size, administrative scheduler settings, etc.), but I suspect findings on a given cluster will generalize to other clusters.

Really appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update 2

Ok, for what I expect will be my final update for this answer, I compared the following:

1. `samtools 1.14` + `zlib`
2. `samtools 1.15` + `libdeflate` (this is a different version, but shouldn't have a major effect. They released a new version just before I asked cluster admins to compile against `libdeflate` and didn't notice until later.)
3. `sambamba v0.8.2`

**Note**: This time I used the following settings:

1. Only two samples instead of three
2. Max `Nextflow` queue size of 30 to avoid too many threads reading from the same two files.
3. I tested CPU requests from 1 to 7 (step size 1) and then from 9 to 17 (step size 2).
4. For jobs where I allotted few CPUs and low memory, I provided a 200% buffer to prevent the jobs from failing with `OUT OF MEMORY` errors. i.e., I gave the `SLURM` job 2x the amount of memory than I told the tools they could use. `sambamba` was the worst offender for exceeding memory in these conditions, but I gave them all 200% buffer to keep comparisons equal.

Seems pretty clear to me that `sambamba` is the fastest and uses requested CPU resources most efficiently (i.e., is able to use all of the CPUs requested up until ~8 or 9 CPUs). For reference, **the difference between `sambamba` and `samtools + libdeflate` with 9 CPUs is ~10 minutes on average.**

We will certainly be using `sambamba` going forward, probably with ~9 CPUs and ~9GB per thread since I had to provide a 200% buffer in lower CPU/Mem jobs to avoid job failure, anyway.

Again, all code and results are available on my GitHub repository ([Samtools sort optimization test](https://github.com/mebbert/Samtools_sort_optimization_test)).

### (Angle 1) Comparison between `samtools + zlib`, `samtools + libdeflate` (Lsamtools), and `sambamba`

Here, I'm showing the general trend that `real time` decreases with increased CPUs for all three tools, but Mem Per CPU doesn't have a huge effect. `sambamba` out performs `samtools + zlib` regardless of settings. `samtools + libdeflate` out performs `samtools + zlib` until ~11 CPUs, where they perform the same (plot 3 below explains why).

**Interesting finding:** `samtools + libdeflate` performs better than `sambamba` with a single thread, but `sambamba` takes over from there as CPUs increase (again, plot #3 explains why).

[image: samtools, Lsamtools, and sambamba]

### (Angle 2) Comparison between `samtools + zlib`, `samtools + libdeflate` (Lsamtools), and `sambamba`

Here, I'm showing that `samtools + zlib` and `sambamba` performance flattens out at ~11 CPUs (again, plot 3 below explans why).

[image: samtools, Lsamtools, and sambamba]

### Requested CPUs vs. CPU utilization for `samtools + zlib`, `samtools + libdeflate` (Lsamtools), and `sambamba`

Here, I'm showing how well each tool is able to utilize the CPUs allotted to it. It was fascinating to see that `samtools + libdeflate` flattens out very early in it's CPU utilization (i.e., ~3 CPUS) and struggles to cross the 400% CPU utilization with even >10 CPUs. This is why `samtools + libdeflate` performance flattens out quickly.

`samtools + zlib` does a much better job utilizing allotted CPUs, but still lags behind `sambamba` throughout (and is slower, anyway).
[image: CPU usage by requested CPUs]

## Update 1

[image: Realtime vs. CPUs and mem per thread (samtools sort)]

My first plots (below) were showing `duration` on the `z-axis`, which is the time from job *submission* to *completion* rather than job *start* to *completion*. That's why the larger memory requests were much longer in the original plots. `Duration` is still a useful measure, but I'm now including `real time`, which is from *start* to *completion*.

Judging solely by `real time` (above), there is a clear gain between 5 & 7 CPUs (~10 minutes, on average when compared to the same mem-per-thread).

More data coming, including `samtools` compiled against `libdeflate` and `sambamba`.

---

## Original post

I made time to semi-formally look at this. I'm glad I did because the results surprised me. I don't answer all of my questions directly, but these results are good enough to get me going in the right direction.

My code and results are in my `GitHub` repository ([Samtools_sort_optimization_test](https://github.com/mebbert/Samtools_sort_optimization_test)) where you will also find an interactive plot you can download to see the results more clearly (see `SAMTOOLS_SORT/samtools_sort_CPU_and_memory_comparison.tar.gz` in the repository). It's hard to truly appreciate the 3D `plotly` plot until you start rotating it.

**NOTES:**

1. Even though this is from only three samples, I think my results are accurate. I welcome any feedback in case there's a bug.
2. In my experience, `samtools` often exceeds its allotted memory (at least on a `SLURM` scheduler). i.e., the job gets killed by `SLURM`. To avoid this, I requested an additional 20% of memory to provide a buffer for `samtools`. I don't know if this discrepancy is because of `SLURM` or `samtools`, though.
3. These results are using `samtools` compiled against `zlib`. We are preparing a version of `samtools` compiled against `libdeflate`, per @user172818's suggestion. I will add those results once completed. I may also compare against `sambamba`, per @acvill's suggestion.
4. These results are related to my other question about [the best sorting/merging method](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18539/samtools-sort-most-efficient-approach-to-sort-a-single-sample-after-aligning-sp). I will post those results in that question and provide a brief summary here.

## tl;dr (too long, didn't read)

### Primary conclusions based on the plots below

1. **Optimal CPUs** (results as expected): There's a significant gain with some additional CPUs, but it levels off around 7 CPUs (total, not 'additional'; i.e., `samtools sort -@ 6`). I thought we might still see *some* nice gains above 7, but this is probably what most would expect (e.g., similar to what @user172818 suggested).
2. **Optimal memory per thread** (<s>results NOT as expected</s>): <s>There is very little to gain with more than 1GB of memory (per thread); that surprised me. There are *some* performance gains up until ~7GB per thread (~2-4 minutes faster). What really surprised me, however, is that performance dramatically **decreases** as memory per thread goes >7GB</s>. The updated plot (above) shows there is some gain with >1GB mem per thread. When running lots of samples at once (hundreds to 1000), mem per thread seems to play a much larger role (data coming).
3. **Effect from sorting status** (results as expected): Largely in an attempt to do this as quickly as possible (laziness?), I used three samples, where one was from an aligned and unsorted `.bam` file, and the other two were from `.bam` files that had been aligned and sorted, but I then collated them (`samtools collate`), rather than re-aligning them. Unsurprisingly, the collated samples (not the average use case) sorted slightly faster than the
   unsorted sample (average use case).

### Initial opinion

1. **"Small" sample set**: For a small sample set, I would probably use 7 total CPUs and 7GB per thread.
2. **"Large" sample set**: I will probably use 7 CPUs (maybe 5) with only 1GB memory per thread. That will allow the scheduler to keep as many jobs going as possible.

### `samtools sort`: duration vs. CPUs and mem per thread

As mentioned above, an interactive version of this plot is available on my `GitHub`.

**Angle 1**
[image: Duration vs. CPUs and mem per thread (samtools sort)]

**Angle 2**
[image: Duration vs. CPUs and mem per thread (samtools sort)]

## Additional details

Analyses were run on [University of Kentucky's MCC Cluster](https://docs.ccs.uky.edu/display/HPC/MCC+system+overview), which uses `AMD 7702P` processors, using `samtools v.1.14`

Answer (score 8):

I usually use `samtools sort -@4 -m4g`. Samtools will be faster with more threads and more RAM, but I *feel* the gain is not significant. I haven't done a proper evaluation, but I have run samtools sort with different settings from time to time on clusters when I have to consider speed-resource tradeoffs.

When you use samtools, make sure you compile it with [libdeflate](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate), which is about twice as fast as zlib on compression. I don't know if the bioconda version built with libdeflate. You may consider the precompiled binary [here](https://zenodo.org/record/5731013).

Samtools sort, especially with libdeflate, is fairly fast these days. Performance metrics in the other answer are outdated.

Comment: Super helpful info about `libdeflate`. I was not aware of that. I really want to do a comparison, but it's difficult to make the time. I may do it soon, and will try to include a comparison between `zlib` and `libdeflate`.

Comment: Side note: if you want to see if the samtools binary you're using is using `zlib` or `libdeflate`, you can see which libraries it was compiled against using `ldd /path/to/<samtools_binary>`. `zlib` will show as something similar to `libz.so.1`.